# Drag a circle drawn on Canvas to follow user drag on screen (android)

Tags: android, graphics, opengl-es

I have one activity in my Android App for now which is a RelativeLayout with a background color and onCreate I create a number of random colored circles and addViews on to the relativelayout based on the device screen width and height. Here are the code snippets.

```
MyActivity.java

package com.myapp.android;

import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Display;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
     Random randomGenerator = new Random();
     String[] colors = { "#84B62C", "#6A28F2","#F3FA0A", "#DF1FE4", "#0000A0", "#28C9DB",  "#E05323"};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        RelativeLayout main = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_myapp);
      //  Display display = ((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
        int width = display.getWidth();
        int height = display.getHeight();

        int number_side = width / 100;
        int number_down = height / 100;
        for(int i = 0; i < (number_side * number_down) * 3; i++) {
              main.addView(new Ball(this,randomGenerator.nextInt(width), randomGenerator.nextInt(height), 40 * (randomGenerator.nextInt(3)), colors[randomGenerator.nextInt(colors.length)], "BALL" + Integer.toString(i)));
        }
    }
}
```

This works great draws all the colored circles in random throughout the screen as I want it. Looks good. Here is the code for the Ball.java where the circles are drawn.

```
Ball.java

package com.myapp.android;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class Ball extends View {

    private final float x;
    private final float y;
    private final int r;
    private final Paint mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

    public Ball(Context context, float x, float y, int r, String color, String tag) {
        super(context);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor(color));
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.r = r; 
        this.setTag(tag);
 }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawCircle(x, y, r, mPaint);
    } 

}
```

What I am trying to do is let the user touch any one of the colored circle and drag it on the screen wherever they want to but I cannot get them to move. I have not posted any trial code here.

What would be the best way to detect the user touch (this can be onTouch or onLongClick) on any of the circles drawn on screen (one circle at a time especially the one that is touched by the user) and thereafter make the circle (which is essentially a view added to the main Relative Layout View group at run time) to follow the users touch drag action (ACTION_MOVE - my guess) until they release the drag (ACTION_UP - my guess).

I have read some tutorials on this topic but none has been really helpful or applicable to my use case. Also I wanted to ask you knowledgeable guys should I use the 2D Graphics Canvas or OpenGL API in my case so that the drag operation on the circles are very smooth and instantaneous. Feel free to run my simple code, it works fine until the balls are drawn on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

In your implementation, you consider Ball as a View and there are many balls thus there are many Views.

If I were you, I'll consider the whole screen is ONE View and the balls are only sprites inside  that View.

Say, I'll extend the View class or SurfaceView class and have a Collection as attribute to store all coordinates and sizes of balls. Inside onDraw(), it should loop through the collection and draw the balls on correct location with correct size.